# Google App Engine Java Threading: vanilla or modified?

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine

Google App Engine allows using standard `java.util.Thread` and `ThreadGroup` classes, but offer a ThreadFactory (`com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager`) in their API, as well as other related classes.
Does Google add some sort of optimization to Java threading, or Java threads are used as-is and their API is the only way to spawn multiple threads in GAE?